# Recursion on odd to be front, even in the back

Tags: python, recursion

I am new to python.
I am writing a recusion to returns a COPY of the list with odds at front, evens in the back.
For example: [3,4,5,6] returns [3,5,6,4].
How should I break the problem into small pieces.

```
def oddsevens(thelist):
    if thelist == []:
        return []
    if thelist[0] % 2 == 0:
```

Comment: Are you using "yield" for this?  The key is that, if the top number is even, you call recursively FIRST, and then add your number.  If it is odd, you add your number first, and then call recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
if thelist == []:
    return []
if thelist[0] % 2 == 0:
    return oddsevens(thelist[1:]) + thelist[:1]
else:
    return thelist[:1] + oddsevens(thelist[1:])
```

Let me know if you have any further questions!

Comment: Ideally you should add some explanation of what the code does. Even if it is straightforward !